# How to fix "No such file or directory" error with csv creation in Python

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to make a new .csv file, but I'm getting a "No such file or directory" in the `with open(...)` portion of the code.

I modified the `with open(...)` portion of the code to exclude a direction, substituting a string name, and it worked just fine. The document was created with all my PyCharm scratches on the C Drive.

I believe it's worth noting that I'm running python on my C: Drive while the directory giving me issues exists on the D: Drive. Not sure if that actually makes a difference, but i

```py
path = r"D:\Folder_Location\\"
plpath = pathlib.PurePath(path)
files = []
csv_filename = r"D:\Folder_Location\\"+str(plpath.name)+".csv"

#Create New CSV
with open(csv_filename, mode='w',newline='') as c:
    writer = csv.writer(c)
    writer.writerow(['Date','Name'])
```

I expected the code to create a new .csv file that would then be used by the rest of the script in the specific folder location, but instead I got the following error:

```
  File "C:/Users/USER/.PyCharm2018.2/config/scratches/file.py", line 14, in <module>
    with open(csv_filename, mode='w',newline='') as c:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '[INTENDED FILE NAME]'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The error code correctly builds the file name, but then says that it can't find the location, leading me to believe, again, that it's not the code itself but an issue with the separate drives (speculating). Also, line 14 is where the `with open(...)` starts.

EDIT: I tested a theory, and moved the folder to the C: drive, updated the path with just a copy and paste from the new location (still using the \ at the end of the file path in Python), and it worked. The new .csv file is now there. **So why would the Drive make a difference? Permission issue for Python?**

Comment: Look at the path in the error and then check out the path that you wrote in the code. Can you notice a significant difference? ;)

Comment: Does the directory exist?

Comment: @alfasin They clearly just redacted it.

Comment: You use r-prefix for path string and double backslash in it. This means there is then a real double backslash in the path.

Comment: @MichaelButscher for whatever reason, if the path ends with a backslash, it errors out. I do the \\ on all of my other code and it works just fine. Do you think it's just the code or how the code is being use that's causing the issue?

Comment: @alfasin the paths are copied in the script. I just didn't want any personal information about me or the client put out on the internet. I can assure you they match.

Comment: @Iguananaut I was referring both to the direction of the slashes (slash vs. backslash) as well as the escaping.

Comment: @dnlarralde I'll add, since you are using pathlib you can join paths with `path.pathjoin`, or equivalently the `/` operator, rather than explicit string contactenation with `+`. This will almost always lead to fewer errors. If in doubt use a print statement to see what string you are actually using for the filename.

Comment: @Iguananaut great tip. New to Python still, but I definitely use the print function.  I know the file name came out right both from printing and error code had it formatted perfectly, but the ```with open()``` isn't making the file, so in turn, it can't find it.

Comment: That's not how open works. If you open a file with mode 'w' the file will be created if it does not exist. Get rid of the double backslashes at the ends; you don't need them. And make sure the *directory* exists too.

Comment: @Iguananaut I can get rid of the double backslash, but did you read my comment? I moved the folder to the C: Drive and just copied the directory, and it worked as is. That's the same process I did with the D: drive.

Comment: I keep asking, does the directory actually *exist* or not? When you open a file that does not exist in write mode it will be created but only if the full directory path already exists.

Answer (score 1):

The raw string can not end with one single backslash '\' so what you are using in your code like in `path = r"D:\Folder_Location\\"` is the right thing but actually you don't need any backslashes at the end of your path:

i ran some similar tests like yours and all goes well, only got the same error when i used a non existing directory

this is what i got:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'E:\\python\\myProgects\\abc\\\\sample3.txt'
```

so my bet is you have a non existing path assigned in `path = r"D:\Folder_Location\\"` or your path is referring to a file not a folder
to make sure just run this:

```
import os
path = r"D:\Folder_Location\\"
print(os.path.isdir(path))  # print true if folder already exists
```

better approach:

```
file_name = str(plpath.name)+".csv"
path = r"D:\Folder_Location"
csv_filename = os.path.join(path, file_name)
```

Comment: I'll give that a shot. Any idea about why it would work as is on the C: Drive but not the D: Drive?

Comment: It make no difference which drive you use, I believe your folder in d is not exist or your path is a file not a folder, you will find out once you get the output of ‘print(os.path.isdir(path))’